# In Excel, how can I sum values in a range if the corresponding name matches a name in a different table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Since the title probably isn't that clear, let me explain my problem.
I have a dataset with values corresponding to names:

***Table 1***

```
name      amount
adrian    1
alice     2
austin    3
bob       4
bruce     5
clarice   6
cathy     7
charles   8
adrian    9
alice     10
austin    11
bob       12
bruce     13
clarice   14
cathy     15
charles   16
```

These names are each matched to another name in a table (for this example, I used the first letter of their names, the actual problem is quite different).

***Table 2***

```
name1  name2
a      adrian
a      alice
a      austin
b      bob
b      bruce
c      clarice
c      cathy
c      charles
```

I have a third table, where I would like to sum all the values from Table 1 where the name corresponds with the correct value in the third table:

***Table 3***

```
name    amount
a       this should be 36 (the sum of arian, alice and austin)
b       this should be 34 (the sum of bob and bruce)
c       this should be 66 (the sum of clarice, cathy and charles)
```

I've tried using the following function in Table 3, but this always results in 0. Can someone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

```
=SUMIF(INDEX(Table1;;2);INDEX( <range name 1> ;MATCH(INDEX(Table1;;1); <range name 2> ;0)); <letter in table 3>)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will iterated through the second table and if the Name1 match then it returns the SUMIF() value of Name2 from the first table and sums them all toghther:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,$F$2:$F$9,B:B)*($E$2:$E$9=H2))
```

Notice that the references to Table 2 are limited to the actual data, while the references to table 1 can be full column references.  That has to do with how the formula will iterate.  As it literally will iterate through the second table we want to limit the number of iterations to the data set itself.  While the SUMIF() formula is already optimized and has no detriment to full column references.

[image]

Comment: Great approach.  I beat on this for an hour and couldn't get an answer.  Even tried the de-referenced INDEX().  :-)